# AsyncTask loads all of my fragments, except two - I get blue screen, why?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, fragment

I have absolutely no clue why the next thing happens in my app: I have a viewpager with abuot 20 fragments, the 2..20 fragments get data from http connection, which I would like to use with AsyncTask. The progressbar appears, the http connection gets established and these fragments are good to go. But, I have to other fragments with some static data, they do not need connection, however I establish the connection in the FragmentActivity, so it shouldnt have different effects on those either. But somehow insted of getting those two fragments, I get two blue pages, as the whole fragment was consisted of one blue-backgrounded layout.

AsynTask part:

```
public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends
    AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        int myProgress;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    pager.setAdapter( adapter );
        indicator.setViewPager( pager );

            pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
            pager.setCurrentItem(INITIAL_PAGE);
            pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //http post MYQUERY1 - this works like charm
        getData();
            return null;


}

 }
```

onCreate() part:

```
setContentView( R.layout.main );
context=this;
//bblablabla
pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

//for viewpager
pager = (ViewPager)findViewById( R.id.viewpager );
adapter = new GoogleMusicAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById( R.id.indicator );


fragments.clear();
fragments.add( TabMyList1.class.getName());
fragments.add( TabMyList2.class.getName());   //these 2 are blue

fragments.add(TabListFromNet1.class.getName());
//.... these work
fragments.add(TabListFromNet18.class.getName());

mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter1(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);


new BackgroundAsyncTask().execute();
```

So how is this possible? My fragments do not require any more work, especially the 2 static fragments, why are those blue?
Thank you very much in advance, I am struggling with this problem for a while now.

Comment: I read your title and thought "how did they get a BSOD on an android device"

Comment: I do not understand, but I put the fragment clear, and fragment.add methods to the doInBackground part.. and now it works. Anyone could give me an explanation?